Listen to MySQL changes via logstash
I have configured logstash to read MySQL data and transfer it into elastic indeces, I was wondering if there is a way other than assigning a scheduler in the input stream where I can make logstash listen to changes in the MySQL datasource by itself without the need to manually run commands to get MySQL updates.
input {
    jdbc {
      jdbc_driver_library => "path\to\mysql-connector-j-8.4.0.jar" 
      jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db" 
      jdbc_user => "root" 
      jdbc_password => "pass" 
      jdbc_paging_enabled => true
      use_column_value => true
      tracking_column => "id"
      tracking_column_type => "numeric"
      clean_run => false
      statement => "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id > :sql_last_value"
    }
  }
  filter {
    mutate {
      copy => { "id" => "[@metadata][_id]"}
      remove_field => ["id", "@version"]
    }
  }
  output {
      elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
          index => "subscribers_idx"
          user => "elastic"
          password => "pass"
      }
  }


There are two ways to trigger logstash jdbc input plugin, schedule and manuel.
If you want to have a near real time sync between MySQL and Elasticsearch you can check debezium solution.
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html

Is it an alternative approach for logstash? or we will use logstash eventually?

You can use schedule for logstash. There is no built-in solution except schedule.
